# How do I pass the deleted row name from a grid in jQuery to controller(server-side) with ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I have added a row to a grid in jQuery success function, like this(edited adding Rob and Fleix comments):

```
 $(function() {

        $('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {
            alert("del");
           // e.preventDefault();

jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Upload/Remove",
            data: "removefile=" + stringhtml// error console shows it as undefined
        });

            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        });
            $("#uploadForm").ajaxForm({
                iframe: true,
                dataType: "xml",
                url: "Upload/Index",
                success: function(result) {

        ('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td> ' + stringhtml+ ' </td><td><a href="#" 
                class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
              });
    });
```

the ajax call is not making for remove click ,but is hitting once page is loaded. How to make the ajax call for remove click, with passing the stringhtml?
Could you guys help me out!

thanking you,

michaeld

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind to the click event of the remove links

```
$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Change your row append code to

```
$('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td> ' + stringhtml+ ' </td><td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Even better: `$('#MyGrid').delegate('a.remove', 'click', function() {...`.

Comment: You're absolutely right @Felix, I'll update the answer accordingly. Sorry @Dan; it's annoying when that happens :)

Comment: Hi Rob, Felix and Dan thanks for your reply. I have added into my code and it is working fine .now can i make an ajax call in the click script to do changes in server side? Also how can i have the deleted row "stringhtml" name ?

Answer (score 2):

First, update your "Remove" link so that it is like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove(this.parentNode)">Remove</a>
```

Then implement your `remove()` function like this:

```
function remove(node) {
    node.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(node.parentNode);
    //equivalent:  $('#MyGrid tbody')[0].removeChild(node.parentNode);
}
```

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/nNde4/5/

Comment: I think  you should pass `remove(this.parentNode)`, otherwise you will remove the `td` element, and not the row. And with jQuery, I would do `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`.

Comment: @Felix - Yep, I should have just read your comment instead of playing around in jsfiddle trying to figure out why the wrong node was being removed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid using inline onclick attributes. Instead use `$(selector).bind('click', function(e){});` or `$(selector).click(function(e){});`. In your case, actually using `live()` would make more sense, since you don't have to attach every event over and over. So using the following should work:

```
$('#MyGrid a').live('click', function(e){
    $(e.target).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Also note that you don't have to call this every time you add a row. Call this only once when the tabel is created (on load etc) and it should work just fine.